# Bash script search for files and sleep on every 10 files found

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a bash script that loop through a folder and it s subfolder and print files. This part is working, but I try to put this part in an if condition and that seems I was not able to..

What I want is that on every 10 files found to sleep 10 seconds and then start again from where were left (continue)..

this is what I did

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i x=0
    
if (( $x < 10  )); then
    
find /myfolder -type f -maxdepth 5 | while read file; do
  echo $file;
  ((x++))
echo $x;

done

else

echo "found 10";
sleep 10;
$x=0;

fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```sh
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
    ((++i % 10)) || sleep 10
done < <(find /myfolder -maxdepth 5 -type f -print0)
```

This uses process substitution, `-print0`, `IFS= read -rd ''`, and `printf` instead of `echo` to allow for all legal characters in filenames.

The important line is

```sh
((++i % 10)) || sleep 10
```

This adds 1 to `i`, then checks if `i` is now a multiple of 10. Since the remainder is non-zero when `i` is *not* a multiple of 10, `((++i % 10))` evaluates to true (exit status of 0), and nothing happens. When `i` *is* a multiple of 10, `((++i % 10))` becomes `((0))`, which has a non-zero exit status, and `sleep 10` is executed.

---

Why your approach doesn't work:

Once you have checked if `x` is less than 10, you run the `find | while ...; do ... done` command entirely – there is never any check for the value of `x` until it's done.